# Javascript ajax call adding "?=####" to the end of my call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching

I have a simple ajax command calling a URL to my server:

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET", url: "/action" });
```

And the response from my logs show as `/action?_=1423024004825`

Is there anyway to remove this?

Comment: if it's simple, you can use a regular xmlhttprequest instead of jQuery...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_=#### is a cache buster. When you have the cache setting set to false it will append that to the query string to make it so browsers think it is a new request and not use a cached version of the response.

To stop it from getting appended just change the setting to true (cached responses will now be used)

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({cache:true});
```

You can also set this on a per request basis by adding the cache setting to the options

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: "/action",
    cache:true 
});
```

> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax
>
> cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be
>   cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work
>   correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending
>   "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for
>   other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL
>   that has already been requested by a GET.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, yes, meant when the setting is cache:false it uses the parameter. Is my wording confusing?

Comment: I'm not saying to "not cache", I'm saying when its setup to not cache that is when it adds it. I'll reword to be more clear. :)

Comment: I'm making an ecommerce website. 
In my cart section of the webpage I can increase or decrease the product quantity.

Comment: I'm making an ecommerce website. When I add products to the cart and try to increase the product quantity with increase and decrease buttons with an ajax post request , my URL gets appended with a ?# at the end and then makes a request on the next button click.

How do I prevent the ?# from getting appended to the end of my url. And make normal ajax request with by post method.